# Creatinng a custom Toast view

Tags: android

I want to create custom Toast view like

```
public class SMSToast extends Activity {

    public void showToast(Context context, String message) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_sms, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.toast_sms_root));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_sms_text);
        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(context);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

and in BroadcastReceiver on onReceive method

```
SMSToast toast = new SMSToast();
                        toast.showToast(context, 
                                        "Received SMS from: " + msg_from + 
                                        " Content: " + msgBody);
```

but no message is shown when the code is called. If i use Toast then text is shown. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: SMSToast toast = new SMSToast();
                        toast.showToast(context,msg);                Is this possible to call an activity's method in such a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public class SMSToast{

    public void showToast(Context context, String message) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_sms, null);
       TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_sms_text);
       text.setText(message);
       Toast toast = new Toast(context);
       toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
       toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.setView(layout);
       toast.show();
   }
}
```

Do not extend the SMSToast class from an Activity. make it a simple java class.

```
SMSToast toast = new SMSToast();                          
toast.showToast(context,  "Received SMS from: " + msg_from + 
" Content: " + msgBody);
```

Comment: this SMSToast class is not needed or showToast should be static. Anyway there was no reason to type, documentation gives perfect example, which is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

Please change these two lines

```
 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_sms, null);
and
 Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you see [example form documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView)?
Looks like not.
You do not need to extend Activity! Just use inflater and standard [Toast, with setView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: getLayoutInflater not working if you not extend Activity class. So i can not use it in a class which extend BroadcastReceiver ...

Comment: 5 seconds of documentation searching: `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)`. and context is available in BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file,null);
Toast toast=new Toast(context);
toast.setView(view);
toast.setDuration(TOAST.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```