# Adding Contact while phone is calling

Tags: android

Could you please help me about the adding contact while phone is calling. For example, you have a phone number that is not saved in the phone contact list. While phone is calling how can I show the person's name who have that phone number. I found the person' name who have that number but I cannot post name to the phone screen while phone is calling. Please help me. Thanks..

Comment: This is very vague. Where is the phone number stored if not in the contact list?

Comment: I am keeping it as a variable in the application ,when phone i calling I will post it to the screen like saved number. And then when call end ,I ask user that DO you want to save that number in the contact list ..

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you what I understand from your question:  You want to show Caller Name(which is not in contact list and you find it from other source). And you want to show this name on Incoming call screen?

you should use BroadcastReceiver for this purpose, listen for phone state change in Receiver. and if phone state is ringing you can show a toast message with NAme and other detail you want to show.(I hope you know about BR and how to listen for broadcast intents)

Please find below link where user want to show a custom Toast on Screen. [Custom toast message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11933525/519718)
it is pretty easy.

Comment: will it be like saved number? For example: your phone number is in my phone contact list.while You are calling me,I see your name on the screen. At this point ,by showin custom toast ,can I arrive such purpose?

Comment: You should handle this case, if phone number is stored in the contact list, then dont show the toast.

Comment: I can store the number in the list but while calling is happining , I cannot show the name. The phone number seems like unstored number to the user. Actually, I am trying to write a program that finds the unstored number of mobile phone users and in the process of the calling , post the name to the screen by using origin call service of android

Comment: I got that from your question and hence given you above answer, what else I can do for you?

Comment: Most welcome, Please let me know if you feel u are stuck nywhere while implementing this